# LSHModel on spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, lsh

Apparently, the LSHModel of MLLib from spark 2.4 supports Spark Structured Streaming (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24465).

However, it's not clear to me how. For instance an `approxSimilarityJoin` from `MinHashLSH` transformation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#lsh-operations) could be applied directly to a streaming dataframe?

I don't find more information online about it. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Persist the trained model (e.g. `modelFitted`) somewhere accessible to your Streaming job. This is done outside of your streaming job.

```
modelFitted.write.overwrite().save("/path/to/model/location")
```

2. Then load this model within you Structured Streaming job

```
import org.apache.spark.ml._
val model = PipelineModel.read.load("/path/to/model/location")
```

3. Apply this model to your streaming Dataframe (e.g. `df`) with

```
model.transform(df)

// in your case you may work with two streaming Dataframes to apply `approxSimilarityJoin`.
```

It might be required to get the streaming Dataframe into the correct format to be used in the model prediction.

Comment: I see. If I understand correctly, this means that the model has to be re-fitted on the entire data stream every time a new batch is read?

Comment: Moreover, it seems that for a data stream, `approxSimilarityJoin` has to be computed between each new batch and all the previous data in the stream, in a stateful way. So all data in stream has to saved first. Is this the case or I am not getting something right?